# Order of python notifications with notify()

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, locking

Let's say I have the following code:

```
master_lock = Lock()
x = Condition(master_lock)
y = Condition(master_lock)
z = Condition(master_lock)

def foo_z():
  with master_lock:
     x.notify()
     y.notify()
     z.wait()

def foo_y():
  with master_lock:
    x.notify()
    z.notify()
    y.wait()
```

When you notify one monitor before another, is there any assurance that a thread of the first monitor will be awoken before that of the second, or is the order completely irrelevant to the order in which the calls were made? In this example, in foo_z, could you rely on a thread waiting on x to run before y, and x before z in foo_y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no assurance to the order since the code is executing in multiple threads.